# How can we transfer mp3 files from client to server in socket programming with ruby

Tags: ruby, sockets

hi i have seen code to transfer binary text files from client to server and from server to client. But can i transfer a mp3 format or any audio file from client to server in socket programming with Ruby.!

i tried the following code 
server side

```
file = open('/pentest/windows/songs/temp.mp3', "rb") 
fileContent = file.read 
client.puts(fileContent)
```

client side:

```
sock = TCPSocket.open(host, port) 
data = sock.read 
destFile = File.open('/tmp/temp.mp3', 'wb') 
destFile.print data 
destFile.close
```

it didnot work out .. can you please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Yes. mp3 files are in binary format anyway. And there's no restriction whatsoever on the type of data you can transfer over sockets.

Comment: actually i tried the following code
server side 
file = open('/pentest/windows/songs/mp3', "rb")
 fileContent = file.read
 client.puts(fileContent)
client side:
sock = TCPSocket.open(host, port)

 data = sock.read
 destFile = File.open('/tmp/temp.mp3', 'wb')
 destFile.print data
 destFile.close

it didnot work out .. can you please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

In client

```
        require 'socket'
        SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 10
        TCPSocket.open('127.0.0.1', 12345) do |socket| 
          File.open('c:/file.mp3', 'rb') do |file|
              while chunk = file.read(SIZE)
                socket.write(chunk)
              end
          end
        end
```

In server

```
         require 'socket'
         require 'benchmark'
         SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 10
         server =  TCPServer.new("127.0.0.1", 12345)
         puts "Server listening..."            
         client = server.accept       
         time = Benchmark.realtime do
           File.open('c:/file.mp3', 'w') do |file|
             while chunk = client.read(SIZE)
               file.write(chunk)
             end
         end
        end
```